# AngularJS nested controllers - How to call external controller's functions

Tags: angularjs

I'm following an exercise in a book, so I don't know if I'm doing any mistake.
I have two controllers both with a function with same name:

```
app.controller('externalController', ['$scope', function(scope){
  scope.aFunction(){
  //Some code...
  };
}]);

app.controller('innerController', ['$scope', function(s){
  s.aFunction(){
  //Some code...
  };
}]);
```

In the book, the function of the external controller is calles in this way:

```
<div ng-controller="externalController as Ext">
  <div ng-controller="innerController">
    <button ng-click="Ext.aFunction()>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

this doesn't work for me, can anyone tell me if I'm doing any mistake or if there's something wrong in the code?
Thanks a lot.
mauro

Answer (score 0):

Basically your are using controller as syntax, and you bounded `aFunction` inside controller `$scope` rather you should be bound it to controller `this`.

When using `controllerAs` syntax controller variables and method should bounded to `this`(context) and when you use `controller as` the controller `context`(this) exposed on HTML via its `alias`

```
app.controller('externalController', [function() {
  var Ext = this;
  Ext.aFunction = function() {
    alert('Function Called');
    //Some code...
  };
}]);

app.controller('innerController', [function() {
  var inner = this;
  inner.aFunction = function() {
    //Some code...
  };
}]);
```

[**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eFqFhFJjbQC4JVQPsC1B?p=preview)

Comment: Can you please help me with this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893716/how-to-store-reference-of-all-parents-for-each-of-the-nested-child

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @MauroGhiglia does this answer helped you?